# permission to access /framework/main.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silverstripe

I am using silver strip and some how my htaccess file got deleted from FTP and then i found htaccess for silver strip and now my htacess is.

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
<Files *.ss>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

</Files>

<Files web.config>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 403 /silverstripe-cache(/|$)
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA]

</IfModule>

### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

But i am still getting same issue 403 forbidden.

[image: screenshot]

Anybody know what i have to with my htaccess ?
Please do let me know if i missed anything to explain.
Much appreciated

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access when you get 403 ?? Please provide information on your `<Directory />` directives, if this all you have in your .htaccess then please provide information from httpd.conf .. You may want to put all the content, there is no sceret in it .. Also, please provide the error logs ..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `AllowOverride All` is set in your httpd.conf file